# condition where two dots is typed it should print no?

Tags: c

First time posting here, having a problem with this code.
I want it to print no when there is more than 1 dot, for instance '2..5'.
Tried to put the following if statement:

```
if(num[i] == '..'){
printf("no \n);}
```

however with no success.
Im new to programming!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char *num = argv[1];

        if (num[0] == '+' && strlen(num) >= 2 || num[0] == '-' && strlen(num) >= 2 || num[0] == '.' || (num[0] >= '0' && num[0] <= '9'))
        { 
            for (int i = 1; i < strlen(num); i++) { 
                if (!(num[i] == '.' || (num[i] >= '0' && num[i] <= '9')) ) {  
                    printf("no \n"); 
                }
            }
            printf("yes \n");                  
        } else {
            printf("no \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use braces `(` and `)` in your if. It is unclear in what order the conditions must be executed (lookup operator precedence too).

Comment: There is a brace missing after `printf("yes \n");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(!(strcmp(num[i], "..")))
```

instead of

`if(num[i] == '..')`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i have fixed that.

Comment: i used your way but know when I type in anything it just crashes!

Comment: Sorry, but `num[i]` is a `char` and `strcmp(3)` requires a `char *`.  Have you tested your solution before posting?  If you haven't, please state it so, as you are feeding with incorrect solutions.  You have to use `num + i` or `&num[i]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing numbers is not trivial. But the following works:

```
double parsenum(const char *num)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    int neg= 1;
    double result= 0.0;
    int nFraction=1;

    while (num[i]=='-' || num[i]=='+') {
        neg= neg * (num[i]=='-'? -1 : 1);
        i++;
    }
    while (num[i]) {
        if (num[i]>='0' && num[i]<= '9') {
            if (nFraction==1) {
                result= result * 10 + (num[i]-'0');
            }
            else {
                result= result + ((double)(num[i]-'0') / nFraction);
                nFraction *= 10;
            }
            i++;
        }
        else if (num[i]=='.')
        {
            if (nFraction>1) {
                printf("%s: no\n", num);
                return 0.0;
            }
            nFraction *= 10;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s: no\n", num);
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
    result *= neg;
    return result;
}
```

Test inputs:

```
printf("%f\n",parsenum("2..5"));
printf("%f\n",parsenum("-2.5"));
printf("%f\n",parsenum("--2.5"));
printf("%f\n",parsenum("2.5.6"));
printf("%f\n",parsenum("++2.555"));
printf("%f\n",parsenum("255.555"));
```

Comment: oh looks good thanks a lot! i fixed the original code by adding: if  (num[i] == '.' && num[i + 1] == '.')